# Can't access method of companion class from companion object

Tags: scala, object, methods

I thought that I can access every method of the companion class from my companion object. But I can't?

```
class EFCriteriaType(tag:String) extends CriteriaType
{
  // implemented method of CriteriaType
  def getTag = this.tag   
}

object EFCriteriaType
{
  var TEXT: CriteriaType = new EFCriteriaType("text")

  override def toString = getTag
}
```

Compiler error:
not found: value getTag

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I totally agree with @MatthewFarwell response. Besides, I think you want the toString method to be inside the class instead the companion object.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are trying to call the method `getTag` in `object EFCriteriaType`. There is no such method in that object. You could do something like:

```
object EFCriteriaType extends EFCriteriaType("text") {
  override def toString = getTag
}
```

Thus making the companion object a kind of template.

You can access members not normally accessible in a class from a companion object, but you still need to have an instance of the class to access them. E.g:

```
class Foo {
  private def secret = "secret"
  def visible = "visible"
}
object Foo {
  def printSecret(f:Foo) = println(f.secret) // This compiles
}
object Bar {
  def printSecret(f:Foo) = println(f.secret) // This does not compile
}
```

Here the private method `secret` is accessible from `Foo`'s companion object. Bar will not compile since secret is inaccessible.

Comment: Ok. I think I understand. I do need an instance of the companion class to call a method of it. If I move the _toString_ method to the companion class, it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do here, but you need to call getTag on an instance of the class:

```
override def toString(x:EFCriteriaType)  = x.getTag
```

Comment: I want to override the method _toString_ and simply return the _tag_. I can't pass an object to toString, or it will become an overloading.

Answer (score 4):

Just to detail Matthew answer, which is the right one:

> A companion object is a singleton but a class is not. a singleton. The companion
>   object can access the methods of the class in the sense that a private
>   member of the class C can be called in its companion object C.

To call a member of a given class, you need an instance of that class (even if you are not doing that from a companion object)

Answer (score 1):

follow this example, please:

```
import scala.math._

case class Circle(radius: Double) {
  import Circle._
  def area: Double = calculateArea(radius)
}

object Circle {
  private def calculateArea(radius: Double): Double = Pi * pow(radius, 2.0)
}

val circle1 = Circle(5.0)

circle1.area
```